# fopen Permission denied, Ubuntu, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu

I was trying `fopen` for my project. Which running on Ubuntu with CodeIgniter PHP framework. The result was like this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fopen(testFile.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Filename: controllers/home.php
Line Number: 10

can't open file
```

By the way, here are my code on Controller:

```
public function create_file(){
    $ourFileName = 'testFile.txt';
    $ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'r') or die ("can't open file");
    fclose($ourFileHandle);
}
```

I looked at that code, and I thought that there is should be a path where I open the file, right? If yes, where should I put the path? Because, I followed this code from this tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filecreate.php.

One thing that make me confuse is, there is no file `testFile.txt` and I wanna create it, but how to give the permission to create it. Because terminal will say `No such file or directory for the file`. What should I do?

I've also tried to run the `chmod` on `www` directory. But, it still didn't work.
Hope anyone help me to handle this problem. Thank you...

Comment: Did you try to give that file chmod 777 or 755 with sudo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 2 ways :

1.) chmod www directory to 777 by this command "sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www".
This will give permissions recursively to all sub-folders and files.

2.) If you create any new folders (or projects in www directory) in future after the 1st step , then follow above :

```
=> Right click on your current project folder
=> Scroll to Properties
=> Scroll to permissions
=> Add permission for "Create and Delete files" for owner, group, others.
=> Now click on "Change permission for enclosed files"
=> Give appropriate permissions for files and folders there.
```

All done. Now fopen() should not give that warning.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Hari. I've tried it, but when I clicked on "Change Permission for enclosed files" the file access turned to none (--). what should I do?

Comment: Hello Nana, First of all chmod www directory to 777 by this command "sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www" , after that follow the above process. My answer modified.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open terminal
2. Go to that directory which has the testFile.txt
3. type: sudo chmod 755 testFile.txt (or use 777 for writing)

---

To create a file with terminal:

```
sudo touch testFile.txt
```

To create a file with php if not exists:

```
fopen('testFile.txt', 'w');
```

Note: If you are not the owner that folder you can not write.

Be sure to parent folder / directory has at least 755 chmod.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Canser. I've tried it, but still doesn't work. One thing that make me confuse is, there is no file testFile.txt and I wanna create it, but how to give the permission to create it. Because terminal will say "No such file or directory for the file". What should I do?

Comment: You are searching that file on the same directory that your .php file. Do you realize that? So you have to go to that directory which your .php file placed, and create a file in that directory.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change the permission of the file you are trying to open. Also you didn't mentioned whether you want to read or write to the file. In general you can give permissions to the file as below:

```
chmod 777 testFile.txt
```

Or In case you want full www directory and its contents to have all permissions recursively, try this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 www/
```

After doing the above you should be able to open the file, as below code does:

```
$handle = fopen("testFile.txt", "r"); // for reading
```

or

```
$handle = fopen("testFile.txt", "w"); // for writing
```

Change your function as below:

```
public function create_file(){
$ourFileName = 'testFile.txt';
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, "w") or die ("can't open file");
fclose($ourFileHandle);
```

}

Comment: Hi, mSatyam. Thanks for your advice. I've tried it but still doesn't work. One thing that make me confuse is, there is no file testFile.txt and I wanna create it, but how to give the permission to create it. Because terminal will say "No such file or directory for the file". What should I do? thank you.

Comment: if the file is not already created you should open it with write mode, which creates the file if not already created.
$handle = fopen("testFile.txt", "w"); // for writing.
I have edited my post including changes need to be done in your code.
One more thing if file is not already present why you what to read from it. One will only read from a file which exists.